# Binding object to select dropdown via angular - set value and access the drop down values

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, ng-options

I have an object with properties

> SelectedWeek -string - for ex: "2"
>
> SelectedWeekRange
>
> Dictionary
>
> Key, Value
>
> For ex:
>
> SelectedWeekRange.Key ="1" SelectedWeekRange.Value="1/1/2017 - 1/8/2017"
>
> SelectedWeekRange.Key ="2" SelectedWeekRange.Value="1/9/2017 -
>   1/16/2017"

I am trying to bind that object to select via angular.

I want to bind all the rows to select dropdown and set the active week as selected.

This code does that, however I need to do these

```
<select ng-change="Change()">
            <option ng-selected="{{val==myObjectName.SelectedWeek}}" ng-repeat="(key,val) in myObjectName.SelectedWeekRange" value="{{key}}">{{val}}</option>
 </select>
```

> Dropdown select : --------------
>
> TextBox field: ------------------

load the data based on the data being selected on the above dropdown and on change of dropdown value, this data will change.

> I need to do a load and change event, how to get the selected value
>   from dropdown and use that to fill in other data?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Any inputs will help?